# Continuous Integration: Deploy to different Firebase projects from one repository

Tags: node.js, firebase, webpack, vue.js, bitbucket-pipelines

### Tech Stack

- Bitbucket Pipelines
- Docker
- Node
- Webpack
- VueJS 2
- Firebase

### Question

Which piece of technology above do I use to reconfigure the Firebase APIKeys before building? I think it should be done in Webpack. Can you point me to an example? I'm a Webpack Noob.

### The Issue

When I use Webpack to build the Vue project, I need to change the `$FIREBASE_API_KEY` and other config options based on the branch that Bitbucket Pipelines was triggered from. If I check-in a change to "inflight" on Bitbucket, Pipelines should build and deploy with the `$FIREBASE_API_KEY` (and other props) that match the firebase project, "dev".

```
// Firebase Config
let config = {
    apiKey: "$FIREBASE_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "my-project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com",
    databasecloudfunctionsUrl: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-project",
    storageBucket: "my-project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xyz123"
}
```

### Details

The config info you see above currently lives within `my-project\src\validation-service.js`

Seems, I need to define $FIREBASE_API_KEY (and the other props) in a separate file that Webpack can manipulate.

Does Docker have a roll in updating the APIKeys and other configs for deploying Dev/Prod from Inflight/Master?

### Examples - similar tech

- https://github.com/bartw/multi_env_webpack_travis_app
- https://hackernoon.com/continuous-deployment-of-a-webpack-app-to-multiple-environments-using-travic-ci-d2c6f22eac50
- https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/tips-for-scripting-tasks-with-Bitbucket-Pipelines

Comment: I am now using **Bitbucket's Environmental Variables** to securely store the firebase API key. Somehow I must use the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` with these environment variables to build a dev or prod version of the VueJS app. I guess this is where Webpack comes into play...maybe.

Comment: I need to get my Docker Image sorted before I begin working with Bitbucket Pipelines. I am currently struggling to `npm run dev` within the Docker Container. `npm run build` works great in the container, but I don't yet understand how to assign and forward ports correctly.

Comment: I am working with the Docker Image, but struggling to see the vue project from the running container. I have this questions posted: [docker/vue/webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497211/docker-container-running-vue-cli-welcome-page-on-localhost-this-site-can-t-be-r)

Comment: I was able to [build and localhost my VueJS/Webpack/Firebase project from a Docker container on my Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497211/docker-container-running-vue-cli-welcome-page-on-localhost-this-site-can-t-be-r). But, this is not useful for a continuous integration pipeline. Instead, I need Docker to setup a Node/NPM project with no Code. Bitbucket Pipelines will use this Docker image, pull in my code, `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

**Webpack**

Webpack makes it possible to configure Client API Keys for different environments, like Prod or Dev.

I created this project with `vue-cli` and chose the `webpack` option. This creates folders and files to configure Continuous Integration for multiple environments.

In my specific case, I saved my two Client API Keys in `dev.env.js` and `prod.env.js`. These .js files are in the `config` folder created by `vue-cli`.

I used [This Tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/demistifying-vue-webpack/) to gain an understanding of how Webpack uses files in the `build` folder. For `vue-cli`, keep and eye on `NODE_ENV` and `'"production"'`

### More

There are other Secret API Keys that this application needs access to when deploying. For this, I use **Environmental Variables** in Bitbucket Pipelines. Although Bitbucket Pipelines uses Docker Images to build and deploy, it is the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` that can reference encrypted [environmental variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html) from Bitbucket, i.e., `$PROD_FIREBASE_API_KEY`, `$DEV_FIRBASE_API_KEY`.