# Docker container running vue-cli Welcome Page on localhost: This site can’t be reached

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

### Question

I would like to see the vue-cli welcome page in chrome, running from a Docker Container on my Mac. I am struggling to set up the proper configuration for this to work. What am I missing? Here is what I have tried.

### Steps

*Installed*

1. Docker for Mac - 17.12.0-ce
2. npm 5.6.0
3. vue-cli 2.9.3

*Command Line*

1. `$ vue init webpack docvue`
2. `$ cd docvue`
3. `$ npm install`

*Files*

After running the commands above, I now have the vue example project ready to build with webpack.

```
$ ls
README.md       config          node_modules        package.json        static
build           index.html      package-lock.json   src
```

Within `/docvue/` I can `npm run dev`, and I see:

```
> docvue@1.0.0 dev /Users/dchaddportwine/Startup/docvue
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 95% emitting                                                                        

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 4695ms                                                                              12:17:04 PM

 Your application is running here: http://localhost:8080
```

And in Chrome at `http://localhost:8080/#/` I see the Vue Welcome page.

**Build the Docker Image**

Now it's time to build the Docker Image using this Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

*Command Line*

```
$ docker build -t cportwine/docvue .
Successfully built 61bc30c3695b
Successfully tagged cportwine/docvue:latest
```

And now it's time to run the Docker image in a container:

```
$ docker run --rm -d cportwine/docvue
34ba43323723c046869775f6f00e11b895c4124680784ebcaff7f711c99fc82d
```

And check the logs:

```
$ docker logs 34ba43323723c046869775f6f00e11b895c4124680784ebcaff7f711c99fc82d

> docvue@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> npm run dev


> docvue@1.0.0 dev /usr/src/app
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 78% advanced chunk op DONE  Compiled successfully in 4383ms16:56:56                 

 Your application is running here: http://localhost:8080
```

### Problem

In chrome, at `http://localhost:8080/#/` I get "This site can't be reached".

The running container looks like this:

```
$docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
34ba43323723        cportwine/docvue    "npm start"         7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8080/tcp            agitated_payne
```

### What if

What if I run the Docker container using the publish option:

```
$ docker run --rm -p3000:8080 -d cportwine/docvue
2f9dd0bf1caa11d96352012913eb58c7883e1db95a7ceb72e2e264184c368261
```

And check the logs:

```
$ docker logs 2f9dd0bf1caa11d96352012913eb58c7883e1db95a7ceb72e2e264184c368261

> docvue@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> npm run dev


> docvue@1.0.0 dev /usr/src/app
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 78% advanced chunk op DONE  Compiled successfully in 4438ms17:08:09                 

 Your application is running here: http://localhost:8080
```

### Problem 2

Wait, is this better?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2f9dd0bf1caa        cportwine/docvue    "npm start"         8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->8080/tcp   zen_liskov
```

In chrome, at `http://localhost:3000/#/` **Now** I get "This page isn’t working - localhost didn’t send any data."

But I do not see the Vue Welcome page.

Comment: Were you able to get the vue ui command to work in docker by chance? I could not get this to work and curious since it's very similar to what you are doing here.

Comment: Joseph, Yes, I was once seeing my Vue app running in chrome from a docker container. But it was a misguided step toward Continuous Integration. I did not ever end up using Docker this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well you solved part of your problem... you NEED to publish the serving port (in this case 8080) to some port on your local machine (could also be 8080 or 3000 like you have), but it looks like you figured this out already.

The other problem is that the webpack-dev-server is using "localhost" for a host, which needs to be "0.0.0.0" to work in Docker. You can overwrite the host config using an environment variable, so try this command instead:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -e "HOST=0.0.0.0" -d cportwine/docvue
```

The logs should say:

```
Your application is running here: http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

and you should be able to access the site in your browser at localhost:8080.

Since the vue setup is using webpack-dev-server, consider reading this for more info on how to use webpack + Docker: https://medium.com/@andyccs/webpack-and-docker-for-development-and-deployment-ae0e73243db4

Comment: This is a good way to run a vue.js app on docker. but for hot reloading there is a delay and cpu utilization goes to 60% on a mac and increasing.  hot reload delay starts with 5 seconds and it also increased next time when you change